# Sum In Correlated SubQuery in MySQL - Using Same Table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table that has multiple payments occuring on different dates each month. I would like the query to return a row for each individual payment and in that same row return the SUM of all payments for that month/year.

My table structure is:

```
   tbl_or_Distri
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `investment_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `inv_distri_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `trade_date` datetime NOT NULL,
  `pay_date` datetime NOT NULL,
  `amount` double NOT NULL,
  `perc_return` double NOT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
```

My current inner query is:

```
SELECT
 `investment_id`,
 SUM(`perc_return`) as perc_return,
 SUM(`capital_return`) as capital_return,
 SUM(amount) as TotalAmount, 
 CONCAT(MONTH(pay_date), " ", YEAR(pay_date)) as short_date,
 MONTH(pay_date) as pay_month,
 YEAR(pay_date) as pay_year
FROM `tbl_or_distri`
WHERE investment_id=29
GROUP BY YEAR(pay_date), MONTH(pay_date)
```

The sum(amount), sum(perc_return), and short_date are the 3 records I need returned in each row of the main outer query. The outer query is:

```
SELECT
 `investment_id`,
  amount,
  pay_date
FROM `tbl_or_distri`
WHERE investment_id=29
```

How can I combine these two queries into one? While maintaining good performance?
Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

U could create a view for your inner query.

```
CREATE VIEW NameYourView AS
SELECT
 `investment_id`,
 SUM(`perc_return`) as perc_return,
 SUM(`capital_return`) as capital_return,
 SUM(amount) as TotalAmount, 
 CONCAT(MONTH(pay_date), " ", YEAR(pay_date)) as short_date,
 MONTH(pay_date) as pay_month,
 YEAR(pay_date) as pay_year
FROM `tbl_or_distri`
GROUP BY YEAR(pay_date), MONTH(pay_date)
```

And then use the view in your outer query.

```
SELECT t.investment_id, t.amount, t.pay_date, v.*
FROM `tbl_or_distri` t
inner join NameYourView v on v.investment_id = t.investment_id
WHERE t.investment_id=29
```

I don't know what it does with performance but it would definitely work.

Comment: Martin, just tried this:`SELECT
a.investment_id,
amount,
pay_date,
b.totalamount,
b.short_date
FROM tbl_or_distri a
INNER JOIN
    (SELECT
 investment_id,
 SUM(perc_return) as perc_return,
 SUM(capital_return) as capital_return,
 SUM(amount) as TotalAmount, 
 CONCAT(MONTH(pay_date), " ", YEAR(pay_date)) as short_date,
 MONTH(pay_date) as pay_month,
 YEAR(pay_date) as pay_year
FROM tbl_or_distri as b2
WHERE b2.investment_id=29
GROUP BY YEAR(pay_date), MONTH(pay_date)
    ) b
ON b.investment_id = a.investment_id
WHERE a.investment_id=29`

Comment: And that worked great. Trying to keep all sql logic in the php script so opted out of using a stored view. Right now the table is rather small, just a few hundred records. In short time- there will be over a million...not sure about performance then.

Comment: Keeping all SQL queries in PHP is a choice. I mostly work with MS SQL Server and storing Views in there gives you a real performance boost. Don't know about MySQL though. I read somewhere that a stored view in MySQL gives you the same performance as running the query yourself. But you could still try when you run into performance problems.

Comment: I use to work in vb and mssql and did the exact same thing for the same reason. With php though, the lead designer is particular in the separation of all the different tiers (and trying to maintain re-usability if we change RDMS's in the future)

Answer (score 0):

Do you need the SUM in every row or do you just need that info in the same query? If the latter, then [WITH ROLLUP](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/group-by-modifiers.html) might do the trick for you

```
SELECT
  `id`, 
  CONCAT(MONTH(pay_date), " ", YEAR(pay_date)) as short_date,
  MONTH(pay_date) as pay_month,
  YEAR(pay_date) as pay_year,
  SUM(`perc_return`) as perc_return,
  SUM(`capital_return`) as capital_return,
  SUM(amount) as TotalAmount
FROM `tbl_or_distri`
WHERE investment_id=29
GROUP BY pay_year, pay_month WITH ROLLUP
```

Comment: I'm needing the sum of the month/year in each row. So if May 2011 sum = 1,000 (because of 3 records 5/1/2011 100, 5/10/2011 400, 5/20/2011 500) I need to see: 5/1/2011 100 1000 5/2011, 5/10/2011 400 1000 5/2011, 5/20/2011 500 1000 5/2011